# three js mirror fixed mesh reflections

Tags: three.js, mirror

After adding a floor mirror the model loses its reflection.

The reflections in the mirror are fine, but they don't show on the model itself and I'm not sure as to why (I'm using the newest three.js:r89).

```
var groundMirror2 = new THREE.Mirror( 200, 100, {
  clipBias: 0,
  textureWidth: WIDTH * window.devicePixelRatio,
  textureHeight: HEIGHT * window.devicePixelRatio,
  color: 0x777777,
  recursion: 0
});

groundMirror2.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
group.add( groundMirror2 );
```

In the second last code line: if the *rotation value* is positive the model shows up fine.

[image: sofa with and without mirror in scene]

Comment: Please, read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: What do we see in the image? What mirror? Which model? What reflections? How did you do that?

Comment: **1)** Please review and address prisoner849's first comment. **2)** If you can't provide a minimal working example, please provide a picture of the model in the desired state (without the mirror floor).  **3)** If it works when using non-negative rotation, then what's the problem? Just don't use negative rotation

Comment: "If it works when using non-negative rotation, then what's the problem? Just don't use negative rotation"
Because i want reflection on the floor, not a celiing

Comment: @PiotrKrawczyk On the picture, it doesn't look like the sofa is on the ceiling, but it has good reflections.

Comment: @PiotrKrawczyk Can you try the latest version of three.js? Can you link to a simple live example?

Comment: What I mean is: Every negative rotation has an equivalent positive rotation. In your case, you set the X rotation to `-Math.PI / 2`. setting it to `Math.PI / 2` would put it in the exact same orientation. If a negative rotation causes the, and a positive one doesn't, use the positive rotation. (_I am also open to the possibility that there is a communication issue here, and we are using "rotation" to mean different things._)

Comment: @TheJim01You are completely off-base. PI/2 is a quarter-turn.

Comment: @PiotrKrawczyk This may be a three.js bug -- depending on what you are doing. You can try `mirror.renderOrder = Infinity;`

Comment: @WestLangley - YES, this is it
thank you very much

Comment: @PiotrKrawczyk Setting the render order solved the problem?

Comment: yes, I add ".renderOrder = Infinity" and it works

Answer (score 1):

The artifacts you are seeing is a three.js issue. A current work-around is to set:

```
mirror.renderOrder = Infinity;
```

three.js r.89